# How to retain the previous selection data using Angular

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

Have datatable,  click button to loading datatable and select few records through checkbox selection. And again we click the button for reload table, Here initially selected checkboxes are unchecked. Is there any way to retain the previous selection records along with newly fetched data. It would be very great help if will get solution.

```
  loadTable() {
     $('#firstTable').DataTable().destroy();
    let params = new HttpParams();
    dataUrl =
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/master/demo/src/data/data.json';

    this.http.get(dataUrl).subscribe(response => {
      this.persons = response.data;
      this.persons.forEach(f => (f.checked = false));
      this.dtTrigger.next();
    });
  }
```

[Demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/retain-data)